az login issue in deployment
I run bash script in Octopus to upload b2c policy xml.
When using:
az login --service-principal --username $client_id --password $client_secret --tenant $tenant_id --allow-no-subscriptions

I got error: argument --username/-u: expected one argument
Update to use =:
az login --service-principal --username=$client_id --password=$client_secret --tenant=$tenant_id --allow-no-subscriptions

Now I got error: ERROR: Failed to resolve tenant ''.
In both above scenarios, it was able to login despite of the error. But is there a way to get rid of error?

Update:
#tenant_id="0f3xxx"
#client_id="be2xxx"
#client_secret="7028xxx"

tenant_id=$(get_octopusvariable "Octopus.Action.Azure.TenantId")
client_id=$(get_octopusvariable "Octopus.Action.Azure.ClientId")
client_secret=$(get_octopusvariable "Octopus.Action.Azure.Password")

az login --service-principal --username="$client_id" --password="$client_secret" --tenant="$tenant_id" --allow-no-subscriptions

When I use my SP to test, it works without error. But If I use the Azure account set in Octopus, Azure info can't be echo/print in Octopus. Despite of the error, it was able to login.

Abe, and just to confirm, $client_id is defined? i.e. if you echo $client_id it returns the client_id?

Initially, I got the same errors:
az login --service-principal --username $client_id --password $client_secret --tenant $tenant_id --allow-no-subscriptions


az login --service-principal --username=$client_id --password=$client_secret --tenant=$tenant_id --allow-no-subscriptions


The error usually occurs if you dint not declare the variables. Hence, I agree with @Joel Brewer check if the variables are declared by executing echo $client_id to check if it returns the value.
To resolve the error, make sure to declare the variables before connecting to az like below:
client_id="ClientID"
client_secret="ClientSecret"
tenant_id="TenantID"

az login --service-principal --username $client_id --password $client_secret --tenant $tenant_id --allow-no-subscriptions


When I run echo $client_id, it returns the value and similarly check for other variables too:

If still the issue persists, enclose the variables with quotes like below and try:
az login --service-principal --username="$client_id" --password="$client_secret" --tenant="$tenant_id" --allow-no-subscriptions


